# Мгновенная замена символов в contenteditable

Tags: contenteditable, replace

Понадобилось тут заменять некоротые вещи, но столкнулся с проблемой.

http://jsfiddle.net/5eRY3/

Когда ввожу текст, каретка перемещается в самое начало и таким образом вводить что-то трудно. Как решить проблему?

Или же проще скажу, к примеру я скопировал откуда-то слово "тест" и вставил в свой div с contenteditable и он заменился на то-что нужно. Только нужно сделать правильно. А то я тут пробывал setInterval и тоже текст не мог вводить. По таймауту не вариант, нужно мгновенно. Вставил/Ввёл - заменилось.

И да, я могу вставлять или вводить сколько угодно раз. А не так, чтобы 1 раз заменило и все.

Ещё раз ссылка на jsfiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/5eRY3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/5eRY3/1/). Не проверял в осле восьмом, а так - вроде бы работает.